# Adjusting white space between titles and the edge of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create space between the titles (the axis title and the plot title) and the edge of the plot. I tried vjust on `axis.title` and `plot.title` with no luck. Nothing really changed in the plot when I tried various values for `vjust`. I also tried `plot.margin`, but nothing seemed to happen with it either.

**Data:**

```
data = data.frame(Category = c(0,1), value = c(40000, 120000))
data$Category = factor(data$Category, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("One-time", "Repeat"))
```

**Plot:**

```
p = ggplot(data, aes(Category, Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), family = "mono", vjust=-0.5) +
  ggtitle("Title") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,150000)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0), limits = c("One-time", "Repeat")) +
  xlab("X axis Title") +
  ylab("Y axis Title")
```

**Theme:**

```
p + theme(
  panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "blank"), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_line(linetype = "blank"), 
  axis.title = element_text(family = "sans", size = 15), 
  axis.text = element_text(family = "mono", size = 12),
  plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", size = 18),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to do this using `margin`

```
    p + theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "blank"), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(linetype = "blank"), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(family = "sans", size = 15, margin=margin(30,0,0,0)), 
    axis.title.y = element_text(family = "sans", size = 15, margin=margin(0,30,0,0)), 
    axis.text = element_text(family = "mono", size = 12),
    plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", size = 18, margin=margin(0,0,30,0)),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
  )
```

Note that margin requires a four inputs and they specify the space in the order top,right,bottom,left.   Also note I'm using the developmental ggplot2 version so my title default is left justified. 'hjust' and 'vjust' worked in older versions of ggplot2.

[image]

Comment: Hey, that worked! It seems that margin cannot be set on the higher level `axis.title` and instead needs to be set on the individual axis levels (`axis.title.x.` and `axis.title.y`).

Answer (score 6):

You can also give a "-ve" value to margin argument to pull the title closer to the plot.

```
gg_1 +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, 
                                  hjust = 0.5, 
                                 family = fam_3,       
                                   face = "bold", 
                                 margin = margin(0,0,-10,0))
```

[image]