# Changing the scale of a plot in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot in R with ggplot2, however if I want to change the scale of the y-axis my plot shifts down (see second image). So if I specify the scale of the y-axis, the 0 will be below the plot and the distance between the title and plot will increase. How can I get my plot back up? So, it looks like the first picture? And everything is visible.

Code first plot:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_count() +
  labs(title = "Iris dataset",
       x = "Sepal Length",
       y = "Sepal Width") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c(0:5))

plot
```

Without specifying the scale of the y-axis, my plot looks like:
[image]

If, I specify the scale of the y-axis with `scale_y_discrete(limits = c(0:4))` my plot looks like this:
Code

```
plot 2: plot <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_count() +
  labs(title = "Iris dataset",
       x = "Sepal Length",
       y = "Sepal Width") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c(0:5))

plot
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use `scale_y_continuous` instead.

Comment: @MKR I tried, unfortunately it does not work. My variable is discrete and if I use `scale_y_continuous`, then no points shows up in the plot

Comment: Tom, check my edit to see how to use @MKR 's suggestion. I would still use `ylim()` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would instead use `ylim()`:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_count() +
    labs(title = "Iris dataset",
         x = "Sepal Length",
         y = "Sepal Width") +
    ylim(0, 5)
```

[image]

From `help("scale_y_discrete")`:

> For simple manipulation of scale labels and limits, you may wish to use labs() and lims() instead.

You can alternatively use `scale_y_continuous()` as mentioned in a comment if you change `limits = c(0:5)` to `limits = c(0, 5)`:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_count() +
    labs(title = "Iris dataset",
         x = "Sepal Length",
         y = "Sepal Width") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5))
```

But, still, my preference would by `ylim()` since you're not doing anything else to the scale.

Comment: Do you know, how I can shift the plot more towards the title?

Comment: @Tom , personally, I cannot discern a difference in vertical spacing between the title and the plot. If you do need to deal with that margin, you can use the `margin` argument of `element_text()` when setting the `plot.title` element of `theme()`; you can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37776455/8386140